# MS SQL Transactions in Views

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-view

Is it possible to create transactions in views? e.g.:

```
CREATE View NewView
AS
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SELECT * FROM TableA
 COMMIT
GO
```

Comment: View is run as a single query, so it is run as atomic operation.  Why do you think you need transaction?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use transaction in Views, as Views are for returning rows from one or more tables, they cannot make changes on your tables hence no need for transactions.

You can of course put your `SELECT` query in a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SELECT * FROM NewView
COMMIT
```

But this is completely unnecessary.
Here you can find some explanations about what transactions are and when to use them:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3304/what-is-a-transaction/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/understanding-transactions-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

If you remember that a view is a read-only operation and transactions are for CUD operations, that should answer your question.

If you are trying to avoid blocking or fetching incorrect data, use the different hints available in your database engine to get the correct data you need.